# Как это сделать в Landing Page?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, layout

у меня вопрос по верстке Landing Page. У меня есть шаблон, в нём есть несколько секций, к которым у меня есть вопрос

**Секция 1**

[image]

**Секция 2**

[image]

**Секция 3**

[image]

**Секция 4**

[image]

У всех этих секций есть кнопка(я выделил их красным овалом), которая должна переводить пользователя ко всем "Сервисам", "Новостям", "Блогам", "Отзывам".  **Как верстать эти страницы?**

Макета этих страниц в шаблоне нет.  Неужели нужно делать целый блог для обычного Landing Page?

Comment: Так этот вопрос надо задавать не здесь, а  заказчику или дизайнеру, который рисовал макет. Поведение всех кликабельных элементов должно быть описано в т.з. помимо самого макета

Comment: Для синих возможно там просто больше карточек должно появится

Comment: Я взял этот макет с "Figma/community", делаю этот сайт для портфолио, поэтому т.з. у меня нет. Как вы думаете, нужно обрабатывать поведение этих кнопок или оставить их пустышками?